# Passar página via $_GET e manipulando a URL via .htacess

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, htaccess, phpmyadmin

Tenho uma página em PHP que mostra os produtos em geral (produtos.php):

```
<?php include_once("conexao.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM produtos";
$result_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Produtos</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Produtos</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <?php while($row_produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_query)){ ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="imagens/produto.jpg" alt="...">
                            <div class="caption text-center">
                                <a href="detalhes.php?id_produto=<?php echo $row_produto['id']; ?>"><h3><?php echo $row_produto['nome']; ?></h3></a>
                                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Comprar</a> </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Eu quero escolher um produto nessa página e ele me levar para a página específica do produto, então eu fiz assim (detalhe.php):

```
<?php include_once("conexao.php");
$id_produto = $_GET['id_produto'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id='$id_produto'";
$result_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row_produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Detalhe</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1><?php echo $row_produto['nome']; ?></h1>
            </div>
            <div>

              <!-- Nav tabs -->
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Detalhe</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Avaliação</a></li>
              </ul>

              <!-- Tab panes -->
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                    <?php echo $row_produto['detalhe']; ?>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
                    <?php echo $row_produto['avaliacao']; ?>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

No arquivo .htacess tentei a seguinte forma:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /detalhes?id_produto=$1 [L,NC]
```

Mas não deu resultado!

Assim, a URL final do detalhe do produto ficaria mais ou menos assim: **site.com.br/detalhes?id_produto=1**
A pergunta é: eu gostaria de que a URL ficasse **site.com.br/nome-do-produto** . É possível fazer dessa maneira? (o caso é porque estou tratando um caso que está padronizado assim, porém não sei como foi feito).

Comment: Para facilitar a sua vida, recomendava fazer `site.com.br/produtos/nome-do-produto`. Poderia substituir `produtos` por outra coisa que possa fazer mais sentido pra vc. A questão é que dessa forma vc poderia sempre carregar a mesma página, pq sabe que se trata de uma visualização de produto, e dentro do seu código pegar TD que está na URL depois dessa "palavra chave" e fazer uma pesquisa na BD. Dessa forma TB não atrapalharia as demais rotas/páginas do site.

Comment: Tks! eu pensei nisso inicialmente! Da forma como mencionei (site.com.br/nome-do-produto) acho que somente conseguiria se criasse páginas individuais para cada produto, correto?

Comment: não sei se daria para criar site.com.br/produtos/nome-do-produto e manipular pelo .htacess para remover o /produtos/ ...

Comment: Possível tudo (ou quase tudo) é. A questão é que se vc quiser remover o `/produto/` da rota, todos os pedidos vão ser direcionados para a mesma página e vc terá que ter um controle do que deverá ser executado (ex: páginas que não são de produtos). Por outro lado, se vc tiver algum identificador na rota, saberá que todos esses pedidos devem ir para uma página específica e serão tratados da mesma forma. ex: `RewriteRule ^produto/slug-do-produto$ /detalhe.php?slug=slug-do-produto`