# Problema: URL amigável no .htacess modificando a Index

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, htaccess

Conforme expliquei no post:
[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/491299/passar-p%c3%a1gina-via-get-e-manipulando-a-url-via-htacess](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/491299/passar-p%C3%A1gina-via-get-e-manipulando-a-url-via-htacess)

Eu tenho uma estrutura de páginas: 1-Index 2-Produto 3-Detalhe (dos produtos)
A página 'Produto' é uma vitrine de produtos e quando vc clica em algum dele é direcionado para a 'Detalhe', que é a descrição do produto.

Eu queria fazer a URL aparecer assim: **nomedosite.com.br/nome-do-produto** ao invés de **nomedosite.com.br/detalhe.php?nome-do-produto**.

Eu consegui mexendo no .htacess com o seguinte código:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?nomedosite.com.br
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ detalhe.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

Options -Indexes
```

Funcionou! Quando clico no produto ele renomeia a URL, porém agora o problema é que ao entrar na Index do site, ou seja, se digitar [www.nomedosite.com.br](http://www.nomedosite.com.br) ele me manda para a página 'Detalhe' (porém fica a URL: [www.nomedosite.com.br](http://www.nomedosite.com.br)) e fica sem qualquer informação lá. O que há de errado com o código acima? tem como eu colocar uma exceção de página?

PS.: Só para deixar claro, a estrutura é a seguinte: **[www.nomedosite.com.br](http://www.nomedosite.com.br)**, **[www.nomedosite.com.br/produto](http://www.nomedosite.com.br/produto)**, **[www.nomedosite.com.br/nome-do-produto-1](http://www.nomedosite.com.br/nome-do-produto-1)**, ..., **[www.nomedosite.com.br/nome-do-produto-n](http://www.nomedosite.com.br/nome-do-produto-n)**

E as páginas são as seguintes: **index.php**, **produto.php** e **detalhe.php**

Comment: Percebi que se digitar uma 'página' (link) inexistente por exemplo www.nomedosite.com.br/nome-qualquer ele direciona para a página detalhe.php (com a url www.nomedosite.com.br) e não dá ERRO 404!